# Error connecting from CLI to AWS windows 2016 instance - Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have created AWS EC2 Windows 16 instance and was able to attach additional volume etc...and so far so good.

I wanted to try to use CLI commands.

Installed CLI on AWS-EC2 windows instance. and did according the instructions attached in the picture below.

when I type "aws ec2 describe-instances I get "Could  not connect to the endpoint URL"
When I was creating the instance, I chose a "Security Group" that had HTTPS enabled.

any help?

[image: error message]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have something wrong in your default profile for the default region.

Check your file at `~/.aws/config` (or `C:\Users\USERNAME \.aws\config` for windows users), you have something like

```
[default]
region=us-west-2a
...
```

Fix the region to region=us-west-2 and then the command will work correctly

You can review the AWS page to make sure you have a valid endpoint http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html, they are classified by AWS services

Comment: I can't find any file under C:\Programdata\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch directory that has [default]

Comment: for windows users its located at C:\Users\USERNAME \.aws\config

Comment: It works after I changed to us-west-2. Any cause why it doesn't work with us-west-2a?

Comment: it does not work as `us-west-2a` is not a valid end-point, you can check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region for valid endpoint